# How can I change the output terminal on VSC ? (I am developing C)

Tags: terminal

Hi I am using VSC for over a month, but before I used CodeBlocks it was using a external terminal and I want do same for VSC can someone help me ?

I googled it but there is nothing

Comment: Do you mean you want to use Terminal (MacOS) or PowerShell (Windows) instead of the built-in terminal in VSC? You could open whichever terminal you want, open the directory via the cd command, and then execute the C file. Example: "cd Developer/MyCode/" -> "gcc hello.c" -> "\a.out" or "\a.exe"